# Is "Only yesterday did I realize she wore two different dresses" a correct sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is *Only yesterday did I realize she wore two different dresses* a correct sentence?

Its meaning is *Although it's a well known fact, until yesterday I didn't realize it.*
The emphasis is on the fact that only yesterday I realized it.

Comment: It's a correct _phrase_, not a complete sentence. You need to go on to say what you realised.

Comment: @KateBunting Only yesterday did I realize she wore two different dresses.

Comment: That is a grammatical sentence, but doesn't make a lot of sense (was she wearing two dresses at once?).

Comment: @KateBunting She wore two dresses to a ceremony (did a costume change).

Comment: Only yesterday did I realise that she had worn two different dresses at the ceremony.